# Show image in label to full size

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I have to show an image as label of screen. I took label to display image but there is some gap between label and tab widget.

I am setting image using stylesheet.

How to remove this gap or space ?

**app.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
    <item>
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
      <item>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>0</width>
          <height>50</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="lineWidth">
         <number>1</number>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string/>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
        <widget class="QWidget" name="tab">
         <attribute name="title">
          <string>Tab 1</string>
         </attribute>
        </widget>
        <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_2">
         <attribute name="title">
          <string>Tab 2</string>
         </attribute>
        </widget>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**main.py**

```
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PySide.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
import sys

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.view = QUiLoader().load("app.ui", self)
        self.view.label.setStyleSheet("background-image: "
                                      "url(label.png);")

def main():
    """ Entry point of application
    """
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    a = Main()
    a.view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Qt Designer, select the vertical layout and then set the `layoutSpacing` property to zero.

Or, in code, you can do:

```
    self.view.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
```